# Magento2 - Add a colour picker attribute in category page

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I am currently using **magento2.1.3** and am trying to create an **colorpicker attribute**. I have created the install script and it has ran successfully showing the attribute in the db. I have added the below code into a **category_form.xml** file

**category_form.xml :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <fieldset name="content">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Content</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">99</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="cat_bannercolour">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Banner Colour</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>    
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My problem is that I don't know where to go from here. I have seen other colorpicker examples for grids but they seem to use a frontend_model which doesn't seem to be available in the ui_component. Any help would be great.

Comment: where you want to set color picker?

Comment: The category color attribute needs to be set in the admin area for each category.

Comment: Check out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189020/magento-2-how-to-add-color-picker-in-ui-form The answer is an implementation using a category attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have to use color picker as a one of the cateogry attribute using ui componant.so i have followed the below steps

Step 1- Create a category attribute with some name (ex:-color_picker_attribute)
[image]

Step 2:- Add below field in app/code/your vendor/yourmodule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

Input:- [image]

Output:- [image]

Comment: Please don't upload images of code.